# Dual-booting a Linux distribution on a Mac with Fusion Drive

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, fusion-drive

I'd like to install a Linux distribution alongside OS X on my 2014 5k iMac with a 3TB Fusion Drive (128GB SSD + 3TB HDD).

Most guides about dual-booting Linux I've found focus on regular partitioning, that is, no Core Storage, and I couldn't find one that helped.

I want to keep OS X in case I have to use software that isn't available on Linux, like XCode or PhotoShop.

My goal is to use Linux as my main system, and I want the root (`/`) partition to live on the SSD to speed up boot, and the home partition to be on the HDD.

Here's the potential solution I found (haven't tried yet):

1. [Split the Fusion Drive](http://www.macworld.com/article/2015664/storage-flash/how-to-split-up-a-fusion-drive.html)
2. Download and install OS X El Capitan on the SSD from the recovery partition
3. Boot into El Capitan
4. [`diskutil cs revert <UUID>` on the Logical Volume which *should* be marked as `Revertible` in `diskutil cs list`](https://awesometoast.com/yosemite-core-storage-and-partition-woes/)
5. Resize the HFS+ OS X partition to around 60 GB
6. Install a Linux distro (Ubuntu, at first) on the free space
7. Create another partition on the HDD for `/home`
8. If it's possible, assign both partitions to a volume group using LVM

Is this possible, or have I missed something that will make it fail?

Comment: Which Linux do you intend to install? Do you intend to have a LVM for Linux?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Ubuntu at first, but if I can install it, I should be able to switch distros by installing the new one on the root partition while keeping my `/home`, right? As for the LVM - I don't think it's essential. If it's significantly more complex than a regular partition scheme, then no, but retaining the ability to change later on would be a plus.

Comment: Actually, I just read up on LVM, and it would make later changes _much_ more convenient. So if it's possible, I will have a LVM.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I edited my question to clarify it.